# how to print file name and total number of fasta sequences?

Tags: shell-script, python, bioinformatics

I have a fasta file namely test.fasta, pas.fasta, cel.fasta as shown below

```
test.fasta
>tile
ATGTC
>259
TGAT

pas.fasta
>ta
ATGCT

cel.fasta
>787
TGTAG
>yog
TGTAT
>In
NNTAG
```

I need to print the file name and the total number of fasta sequences as shown below,

```
test,2
pas,1
cel,3
```

I have used the following commands but failed to serve my purpose

```
grep ">" test.fasta | wc -l && ls test.fasta
```

Please help me to do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a fasta?

Comment: There is no need to use `ls`. `echo` will work just as well.

Comment: What's a "_fasta sequence_"?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor see: ["Can the header line contain arbitrary text in FASTA format?"](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/16341/can-the-header-line-contain-arbitrary-text-in-fasta-format/16396#16396)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what the `-c` option of `grep` (to `c`ount) is for:

```
$ grep -ce '^>' -- *.fasta
cel.fasta:3
pas.fasta:1
test.fasta:2
```

Note that if there's only one matching file, the file name will not be printed. Some `grep` implementations have a `-H` option to force the file name to be printed always:

```
$ grep -Hce '^>' -- *.fasta
cel.fasta:3
```

To get your exact expected output, you just need to replace `.fasta:` with `,`:

```
$ grep -Hce '^>' -- *.fasta | sed 's/\.fasta:/,/'
cel,3
pas,1
test,2
```

(here assuming your file names don't contain other occurrences of `.fasta:` such as `my.fasta:foo.fasta`; of course newline or `,` or `"` characters and potentially whitespace characters in file names would also be a problem if the output is meant to be in CSV format)

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU awk for `ENDFILE` and `gensub()`:

```
$ awk '/^>/{c++} ENDFILE{print gensub(/\.[^.]*$/,",",1,FILENAME) c+0; c=0}' *.fasta
cel,3
pas,1
test,2
```

The above will work no matter if it's 1 or many input files present (as long as it's less than the shell args limit) and no matter which characters are present in your file names as long as it's not `=` (when awk could, in some cases, treat it as a variable assignment - if that can happen then see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Other-Arguments for how to handle it).

You can do the same with any awk:

```
$ awk '/^>/{c[FILENAME]++} END{for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) {f=ARGV[i]; sub(/\.[^.]*$/,",",f); print f c[ARGV[i]]+0} }' *.fasta
cel,3
pas,1
test,2
```

Comment: That doesn't work for filenames that contain `=` characters (and what's on the left side of the first `=` has the shape of a valid awk variable name). You'd want to use `./*.fasta` and strip the `./` in your ENDFILE statement or use `-E /dev/null` and put the `awk` code in a `-e <expression>`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ah, good point. I'll tweak the answer to account for that thx.

Comment: While you're at using `awk`, you could also encode the filename in CSV format (wrap in `"..."`, escape `"`s as `""`).

Comment: All true. I'll add that if the OP asks for it.

Comment: Thank you @StéphaneChazelas and Ed Morton for your detailed explanation and valuable code.  Both codes works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```perl
~$ raku -e 'for dir(test => / \.fasta $/ ) -> $fh { put ($fh,  $_.grep(/ ^^ \> /).elems).join(",") given $fh.lines() };' > outfile.txt

#OR

~$ raku -e 'for dir(test => / \.fasta $/ ) -> $fh { put join ",", $fh,  $_.grep(/ ^^ \> /).elems given $fh.lines() };'  > outfile.txt
```

Sample Input (pwd):

```
~$ ls *.fasta
cel.fasta   pas.fasta   test.fasta
```

Sample Output:

```
cel.fasta,3
pas.fasta,1
test.fasta,2
```

This solution uses Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. The code above relies on Raku's `dir()` and `grep()` routines, and therefore may be useful on platforms where classic shell-mediated file-globbing is absent or restricted (see SO discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69400187/7270649)).

Briefly, `raku` is called with the `-e` option, which tells Raku's compiler (Rakudo) to compile and execute the given one-liner program. The `dir()` method is called with the `for` keyword which tells Raku to loop through the filename values obtained using the filter `test => / \.fasta $/`. Filenames thus found are loaded individually into `$fh` variable and analyzed in a `{…}` block.

Inside the block, reading from right-to-left, `lines` are extracted from the `$fh` filehandle variable, which automatically loads into the `$_` topic variable. These lines (now held within `$_`) are `grep`-ped through to find lines with a `^^` start-of-line `>`, signifying the start of a new `fasta` sequence. Lines thus found are counted using `elems`, and the `$fh` and count are `join`-ed with a `,` comma and returned linewise using `put`.

The OP originally asks for the "file name" to be returned, so technically the code above suffices. However because `$fh` are `IO::Path` objects, it's easy enough to remove the `.fasta` extension: just append the `extension` routine to `$fh` to recognize the `.fasta` extension, and replace it with nothing (`""`):

```
~$ raku -e 'for dir(test => / \.fasta $/ ) -> $fh { put ($fh.extension(""), $_.grep(/ ^^ \> /).elems).join(",") given $fh.lines() };'
cel,3
pas,1
test,2
```

https://docs.raku.org/routine/dir
https://docs.raku.org/routine/grep
https://docs.raku.org/routine/extension
https://raku.org